# Setting a SQL local variable properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, local-variables

**I'm wondering if there is a way to have a local variable use the 'FROM' statement from a SELECT statement that is not declared in the 'SET' of the variable.
I have the following example:**

```
DECLARE @IDNO int;
DECLARE @ORDERQUANTITY int;

SET @IDNO='1';  --TEST VALUE
SET @ORDERQUANTITY=ISNULL(SUM(Table1.QUANTITY), 0);

SELECT
Table1.IdNo AS 'ID No',
@ORDERQUANTITY AS 'Order Quantity'

FROM Table1

WHERE IdNo = @IDNO
GROUP BY IdNo, QUANTITY
```

I have lots of columns which add columns together, and those columns that are added together are derived from statements like those in the `@ORDERQUANTITY` variable.

So instead of having lengthy column definitions in my SELECT statement, I'd like to place things in variables to make the SELECT statement simpler

e.g.

`SELECT @ORDERQUANTITY - @ORDERSCANCELLED AS 'Net Sold'`

The best way to approach this would be appreciated!

(Using SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
SELECT @ORDERQUANTITY = COALESCE((SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM dbo.Table1), 0);
```

If your goal is to make your subsequent queries more readable, I'd suggest shorter variable names and not using `@ALLCAPSFORVARIABLENAMESBECAUSETHEYARENOTVERYREADABLE`.

Also I have no idea what you are trying to do with the `GROUP BY` but it doesn't appear to be necessary at all (and grouping by the constant won't do anything in any case).

Now, I'm not sure I quite follow what you're trying to do. Are you saying you don't want to have to repeat `SUM(QUANTITY)` in the `SELECT` list multiple times, and you want to replace the *expression* rather than the value* with a variable? It's tough to tell from your code, but is this `SUM` supposed to represent the whole table, or just for the given ID? Some ideas:

1. If you are only looking for one row for a specific ID, then use a CTE/derived table so that you don't have to repeat the calculations:

   ```
   ;WITH x AS 
   (
     SELECT oq = SUM(Quantity), oc = SUM(Cancelled)
     FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE IdNo = @IDNO
   )
   SELECT
     [Total Sold] = oq,
     [Cancelled] = oc, 
     [Net Sold] = oq - oc
   FROM x;
   ```
2. If you want to calculate the sums first across the whole table, then do the following so you only have to perform those computations once:

   ```
   SELECT
     @oq = SUM(Quantity),
     @oc = SUM(Cancelled)
   FROM dbo.Table1;

   ... and use those variables later ...
   ```
3. If you're trying to hold the values for multiple `@IDNO` values in one variable, you'll need to think differently about this. Stop thinking about variables as holding tanks when you are dealing with sets of more than one row. Tell us what you actually want to achieve instead of telling us how you think you can achieve it.

Finally, please stop using `AS 'single quotes'` aliases. If you need to have illegal characters or reserved words for column aliases, please us `AS [square brackets]` instead.

Comment: Thanks, to be more clear, I am trying to set the variables, and then use those variables repeatedly in the calculations for the columns in the SELECT statement, rather than repeat the expression (e.g. `SUM(Quantity)` multiple times. My SELECT statement is a separate statement below the SET statement(s), as it also has simple data retrieval operations in it. There is also FROM and WHERE clauses in my SELECT statement...so do I need to use a FROM statement in the setting of the variables, and a FROM statement in the SELECT statement below it which uses those variables to compute values?

Comment: I'm not sure which parts of your new question I haven't already answered.

Answer (score -1):

If what you're asking is if you can do this:

```
DECLARE @ORDERQUANTITY int;
DECLARE @ORDERSCANCELLED int;
SET @ORDERQUANTITY=ISNULL(SUM(Table1.QUANTITY),0);
SET @ORDERSCANCELLED=ISNULL(SUM(Table1.CANCELLED),0);
SELECT @ORDERQUANTITY - @ORDERSCANCELLED
```

the answer is yes

Comment: Your sets don't make sense, because they (like the OP's) reference `Table1` columns but not the table itself.

Comment: Was that his question? How to get the values into the variables?

Comment: no idea, but your 3rd line will fail because it where does it find `Table1.QUANTITY`?

Comment: Right, I know, but I wasn't focussing on that, just taking his code and outputting what I *thought* his question was, i.e., can I use variables in a SELECT clause. "So instead of having lengthy column definitions in my SELECT statement, I'd like to place things in variables to make the SELECT statement simpler" I figured he was just abbreviating to save typing.